# VBA trying to iterate columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating program which should iterate in range from "A1" to "A1000" but i seem to do something wrong. Will be glad for anyone that could help.
This is my code:

```
For i = 1 To 1000
    FinalRngA(i).Add ("A" & Str(i))
Next
```

Comment: For each cell in range("A1:A1000").cells  cell.value=1  Next

Comment: thanks but i need to add "A1","A2",...,"A1000" to FinalRngA

Comment: What's this ... `FinalRngA`?  I think you need to provide more context.

Comment: Ok, here is the whole code.
'Dim ClauseNumber() As Variant, FinalRng() As Variant
    Dim FinalRngA() As Variant
    FinalRngA() = Array()
    FinalRng = Range("A1:A1000")
    'FinalRngA = Array("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "A9", "A10", "A11", "A12", "A13", "A14", "A15", "A16", "A17", "A18", "A19", "A20") 'column A in "Nova Klauzule"
    For i = 1 To UBound(FinalRng):
        FinalRngA(i).Add ("A" & Str(i))'

Comment: @PetrVoborník  please **update your post** with your code and more detail around the current situation, the desired situation, and what you're tried to bring those closer together.  A block of code via comment is near unreadable.

Comment: i figured out the problem, but thanks